# Load all Order with Attributes

Tags: 7, ubercart

How can I load all order by using sql queries or by using predefined methods. I have attributes like One Month and Three Month. I want to get orders and the selected attribute with each order.

Comment: Please show the code/queries you've tried yourself so far so we can help to debug them. We won't write your code/queries for you, this isn't that kind of site

Comment: I am asking about any function like `uc_order_load($order_id)` needs order id. But i didn't found any function that gets all result.

Answer (score 0):

Try [uc_order_status_list](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/api/uc_order_status_list)

**Parameters**:

**$scope** - Defaults to all, but you may specify the scope for the order statuses you want listed based on their corresponding order state. Possible values are - all, general, specific, or any order state id.

**$sql** - Pass this parameter as TRUE to alter the return value for a SQL query.

**$action** - By default, this is empty. Since order statuses are cached, you can pass in 'rebuild' to reload the contents from the database if you are making changes to statuses on a page load.

**Return value:**
The return value will be either an array of status arrays (containing the keys id, title, state, and weight) or a string containing an array of status ids for use in a SQL query.

Comment: This is giving order status list not order list.